# get json data from nodejs to Angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

My `app.js` is-

```
app.get('/post', (req,res) =>{
  let data =
  [{
    userId: 10,
    id: 98,
    title: 'laboriosam dolor voluptates',
    body: 'doloremque ex facilis sit sint culpa{ userId: 10'
    },
    {
    id: 99,
    title: 'temporibus sit alias delectus eligendi possimus magni',
    body: 'quo deleniti praesentium dicta non quod'
  }];

  res.status(200).json(data);

});
```

and my `my.service.ts` is -

```
export class MyService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    fetchData(): any {
        console.log('reaches');
        return this.http.get('/post').pipe(
          map((post) => {
            console.log(post.json());
            return post.json();
          })
        );
      }
}
```

My `sem.component.ts` is -

```
export class SemComponent implements OnInit {
  posts: any = [];

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('reaches');
    this.myService.fetchData().subscribe(posts => {
      this.posts = posts;
      console.log(posts);
    });
  }
}
```

and my `Routes` is -

```
export const myRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'post',
    component: SemComponent
  }]
```

this is my ways to get the json data in angular.

When I run the  url : 'localhost:3000/post'.

It is not reaching to my service.ts code.

It direct show the json data from `app.js` file

[image]

Comment: Does it show any error on the console? I hope your service has the `@Injectable()` decorator?

Comment: @AnkitSharma No, there is nothing in console

Comment: I am just wondering if you are running your Node.js server on 3000, how can it hit your service.ts. Are you running your angular app on 4200 or 3000? Also hitting `this.http.get('/post')` will hit the same domain and append `/post` to it. Hence if you are running angular on 4200, the URL will be formed as `http://localhost:4200/post`.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I am running the nodejs server on 3000

Comment: And where are you running your Angular app?

Comment: It is same as nodeJs server.

Comment: @AnkitSharma First, I run command  `ng build` and then `npm start`

Comment: The result does not show any angular app... Where is the angular app?

Comment: I removed that favicon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177334/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-rupesh).

Comment: And My post method works successfully. The problem is with get method.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    fetchData(): Promise<any> {
      return this.http
      .get("url").toPromise()
      .then((response)=>{
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
}
```

and in your SemComponent you can consume the returned data as follow.

```
export class SemComponent implements OnInit {
posts: any = [];
constructor(private myService: MyService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('reaches');
        this.myService.fetchData().then(data => {
          this.posts = data;
          console.log(this.posts);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: could you access your backend with something like postman and check if you get any data from http://localhost:3000/post ? and obviously the "url" in my code should be change to your backend url.

Comment: Please see above, I have updated my query and add the image of result getting.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your web server (app.js) and angular application on the same port and context. You should try changing the port number and the context ('/post') of one of these.

Collision is here, router path and app.js request context is 'post'.

Please check the port and context of your applications, it should solve the problem.